# Xpath needed to match three different scenarios

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have been reading about xpath axes on w3schools.com and I have been trying to search for help but I am having a hard time figuring out what to actually search for.

I have an xsl stylesheet that is used to transform various xml files into pdf prints.  The part that I am stuck at is that I have identified at least 3 different scenarios when I need to change some formatting.  I have found a way to change the formatting in two of the cases, but the third is a sort of hybrid of the other two, and I keep getting both sets of formatting to be displayed when I only want the one.

Please let me know if any additional information would be useful, thank you!

Scenario 1:

```
<TASK>
    <REVST>Some revised text
</TASK>
```

Scenario 2:

```
<LIST>
  <PARA>
    <REVST />Some Text <REVEND />
  </PARA>
</LIST>
```

Scenario 3:

```
<TASK>
   <PARA>
      <REVST />Some other revised text <REVEND />
   </PARA>
 </TASK>
```

What seems to work with Scenario 1 is having this `<xsl:if test="parent::*TASK/REVST">` in a part of the stylesheet that does a for-each and goes through each "ITEM".
What seems to work with Scenario 2 is to have this test `<xsl:if test="descendant::REVST">` inside the PARA template.

But for Scenario 3, I end up with both displaying, when it should only be the formatting from the PARA template.

Any suggestions?  Or even a suggestion of search terms?  Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

I know I have a LOT to learn, and I appreciate the help that has been provided, but I still don't quite understand how to get this to not show the revision formatting (a bar on the right-hand side of the page) for the entire document when only some of the text has been indicated to be revised?

```
<LIST>
<PARA>
    <REVST/>
    THIS IS SOME TEXT THAT SHOULD BE MARKED BY A REVISION BAR.
    <REVEND/>
</PARA>
</LIST>
```

Whereas a case like this one, I need to show a revision bar for essentially the whole document.

```
<TASK>
  <ELE1/>
    <REVST/>
    <ELE2/>
    <TITLE>The Title</TITLE>
    <ELE3>
      <ELE4>
        <TITLE>General</TITLE>
        <LIST>
          <LITEM>
            <PARA>This is some paragraph text.</PARA>
          </LITEM>
        </LIST>
      </ELE4>
    </ELE3>
</TASK>
```

I tried with what had been presented, but it didn't seem to apply unless I added the * by the text or PARA parts.  I am probably missing something there as well.

```
<xsl:template match="TASK/*text()[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::REVST] and following-sibling::*[1][self::REVEND]]">
    <fo:block color="red" border-right="solid black 2pt" margin-right="16pt">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="LIST1/*PARA/text()[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::REVST] and following-sibling::*[1][self::REVEND]]">
    <fo:block color="green" border-right="solid black 2pt" margin-right="16pt">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

Any additional advice?  I am still stuck :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is how to do this**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match=
 "TASK/text()[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::REVST]
            and
              following-sibling::*[1][self::REVEND]
              ]">

  Processing Type1 of: "<xsl:value-of select="."/>"
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
 "LIST/PARA/text()[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::REVST]
                 and
                   following-sibling::*[1][self::REVEND]
                   ]">

  Processing Type2 of: "<xsl:value-of select="."/>"
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
 "TASK/PARA/text()[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::REVST]
                 and
                   following-sibling::*[1][self::REVEND]
                   ]">

  Processing Type3 of: "<xsl:value-of select="."/>"
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document:**

```
<t>
 <TASK> <REVST/>Some revised text<REVEND/> </TASK>
 <LIST> <PARA> <REVST />Some other revisedext <REVEND /> </PARA> </LIST>
 <TASK> <PARA> <REVST />Some yet other revised text <REVEND /> </PARA> </TASK>
</t>
```

**the wanted result (each case processed in its own way) is produced:**

```
  Processing Type1 of: "Some revised text"


  Processing Type2 of: "Some other revisedext "


  Processing Type3 of: "Some yet other revised text "
```

**Rule to remember**:

Use XSLT as ... XSLT.

This means: always prefer templates to inline `xsl:for-each`. The former results in short, simple, less error-prone, clean, easier to understand and maintain code. The latter results in longer, more complex, ugly, spaghetti-like code that is error-prone, difficult to understand, difficult to extend and maintain.

Comment: Thank you for that advice about preferring templates to inline xsl:for-each.  I have been learning on the go and trying to clean things up somewhat as I can.  The setup with using the xsl:for-each was already there so I thought that was how it was supposed to be.  I have a long way to go :)

Answer (score 2):

> I have been reading about xpath axes on w3schools.com

That's not a good learning strategy. w3schools is very handy for looking up things you once knew but have forgotten, but it's not organized to help you understand the basic concepts. Get yourself a good book.

Your post suggests to me that you haven't understood the important notion of context. The meaning of an XPath expression is critically dependent on what the context node is at the point where it is evaluated. If you did understand context, I'm assuming you would have told us what the context was where these expressions were used.

Comment: Can you recommend any good books?  I find it hard to choose a book without being able to look at it first, and there doesn't seem to be much actually in book stores.

Comment: @froglander, Dr. Kay is the author of the best books on XSLT and XPath. See a collection of links to good XSLT/XPath books and other resources here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339930/any-good-xslt-tutorial-book-blog-site-online/341589#341589

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the full path everytime :

```
/TASK/REVST
/LIST/PARA
/TASK/PARA/REVST
```